# Why getScript will be fail in webkit platform?

Tags: jquery, getscript

Hi All:
     I want to use getScript to load a js file. after load js, I want to get the varaible that defined in test.js file, it can be sucessful in IE browser, however, when in Webkit browser, it will fail, and show teststring is undefined, this is why, Thanks for your help!

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(data, textStatus){
        alert(textStatus);
     var string = teststring;
}
```

//test.js

```
var teststring = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are on localhost and chrome restrict the privileges of file:// and does not treat it as a single domain. 
add `--allow-file-access-from-files` to the command line when launching chrome to disable this security feature

Read more at 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4197